# vmware quiescence snapshot

Tags: vmware, snapshot

I have a question about **"quiescence"** snapshot.

As I understand step of quiescence" snapshot:

1. Freeze FS and Processes
2. Run pre-freeze
3. Make snapshot
4. Run post-script
5. Unfreeze FS and Processes

Is it right? For example if I stop mysql in pre-freeze , is it not necessary to run it in post-script?

Answer (score 1):

You may find this KB article useful:

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1015180

In general, the goal here is to get the file system into a consistent state.  That is to say, if you restore from this snapshot, you want to make sure that your application can re-start from this point.  For many SQL based databases, this implies that transactions should be committed prior to snapshot.  The actual details vary depending on the system you are using.

All of this is managed by guest tools as only the guest can actually quiesce the file system.